# unable to get SAML metadata for Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Setting up a custom policy in Azure AD B2C to connect to a SAML Identity Provider. This requires a SAML metadata endpoint to get the SSO URL and other information.

As per Microsoft documentation the End point link is : 
https://[my-tenant].b2clogin.com/te/[my-tenant].onmicrosoft.com/[my-policy]/samlp/metadata?idptp=[my-technical-profile]

I tried this way but I am constantly getting the same error :

Unable to return metadata for the policy 'B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtention' in tenant 'Mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'.

Is this error due to some fault in my policies ?

Answer (score 0):

Typo?

The usual name is:

TrustFrameworkExtensions

You have:

TrustFrameworkExtention